# Plot a range bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

so I would like to plot a bar plot of the values indicated in the table, I just don't know how to do it. I have an optimal range that I would like to highlight (20-30) and show with bars which of the substrates are within, above and below the optimal range. I'm adding the table and a sketch for reference, hope somebody can help me out, thank you!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a similar concept: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147024/586 It has horizontal bars instead of vertical ones, so one has to swap x and y throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Making bar plot is not that difficult and it requires Tikz library usage. Here is the guide of how to make this: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Pgfplots_package#Plotting_mathematical_expressions
So, you need to use these packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

% We will externalize the figures
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

at the top of your code listing and your plot data inside the the `\begin{tikzpicture} \end{tikzpicture}` environment to start making your plot

like described in the example in overleaf help that I gave reference of:

```
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Year,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar interval=0.7,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,408184) (2011,408348)
         (2010,414870) (2009,412156)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,388950) (2011,393007) 
        (2010,398449) (2009,395972)};
\legend{Men,Women}
\end{axis}
```

So, insted of men &women you'll write types and insted of year you'll write ratio

Comment: If I may nitpick a bit :) Strictly speaking, TikZ isn't required to make bar plots, there are other options. And you're using `pgfplots`, which is not the same as TikZ, though it does use it. And the externalization isn't needed. Finally though, this doesn't actually answer the question as I understand it. The OP wants a bar that goes from a to b, your example has bars that start at zero.

Comment: Exactly, this does not answer the question. I know how to make usual bar plots. I do not know how to make a bar plot with bars going from a to b while highlighting certain range which was from 20-30.

Comment: @Gerda oh...sure, may you provide your code it'll be easier for community to work with it